# How to load data from csv file in ssis using for each loop container

Tags: ssis

Daily SQL Job will start at 12.00. It will run a package that fetch a CSV file from a folder(using for each loop container in ssis). 
Suppose if there no files in that specific folder. You should not run the package until the csv files load into that folder? How we can do this using SSIS .
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a script task, you can check if the file exists in that location with that file extension and then build an expression in the precedence constraint editor. Set the evaluation operation to expression and constraint value to success. Something like the one shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have the job run on a schedule.   If there are no files in the folder, it won't do anything.   The next time it runs, if the files are there, it will process them.